# How to get timezone offset from the timezone name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, timezone, timezone-offset

I have a timezone name like `America/Vancouver` saved in a SQL Server database.
I want to get the UTC offset from the timezone name in SQL like  `America/Vancouver` has `-08:00` offset. So how can I write a query in SQL?
Your help is much appreciated

Comment: The UTC offset at what instant in time? America/Vancouver varies between UTC-7 and UTC-8. That's a relatively simple case, as it's had the same *standard* time forever as far as I can see... but what about time zones that go on to "permanent daylight saving time" for example? (That's what a lot of the European Union might do in the next few years... so Europe/Paris currently varies between UTC+1 and UTC+2, but may be permanently UTC+2 in the future.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I required the daylight saving offset as you mention, basically, I have a users availability time as 12:00 to 04:00 in the SQL table and the user timezone is in `America/Vancouver` So I have to check the work UTC time with the worker's availability time so I need to convert the UTC time to workers timezone and compare the time slot

Comment: When you say "the work UTC time" - you have that as a specific value already? So the question is really "How do I convert a specific instant in time into a time zone using an IANA time zone ID?" (It would be good to edit the question to make that clear.) I don't know whether SQL Server has *any* support for IANA time zones directly - you may need to convert from an IANA time zone ID into a Windows time zone ID first, at which point you could use "AT TIME ZONE".

Comment: You've tagged SQL Server 2005 & 21008 - which are you using?

Answer (score 4):

Use DATEPART with TZ parameter. Example :

```
SELECT DATEPART(tz, (CAST('2021-01-01' AS DATETIMEOFFSET) AT TIME ZONE 'Central European Standard Time'));
```

The result is in minutes.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately SQL Server doesn't yet support IANA time zone identifiers (like `America/Vancouver`) directly.  For now, the best option is to convert from the IANA identifier to a corresponding Windows time zone identifier in your application layer, and store that in your SQL Server.

For example, if you are running .NET in your application layer you can use my [TimeZoneConverter](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneConverter) project:

```cs
string tz = TZConvert.IanaToWindows("America/Vancouver");
// Result:  "Pacific Standard Time"
```

Then you can use the [`AT TIME ZONE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql) function in your SQL Server code:

```sql
SELECT sysdatetimeoffset() AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time'
```

The above will give you the current date, time, and offset in the given time zone, which you can use as the basis for your query against the user's availability (mentioned in the question comments).

Keep in mind that the offset adjustment will be different depending on whether daylight saving time is in effect or not.  Despite the word "Standard" in the Windows identifier, DST is indeed taken into account where applicable.

Alternatively, if for some reason you must do this entirely in SQL Server without converting to Windows time zones, then you will need to rely on projects such as my [SqlServerTimeZoneSupport](https://github.com/mj1856/SqlServerTimeZoneSupport) project.  That one is a bit old and not very well maintained, so I recommend against that approach if you can help it.

Comment: Just a littre precision... AT TIME ZONE is not a function but an operator (in mathematical terminiology...) like BETWEEN, LIKE or IN... and SQL is an interpretation of the relational algebrae !