# ConvertZone() returns NULL using TZDB SQL Server Zone Support

Tags: sql-server, timezone, dst

We are running SQL Server 2008 R2, so for Timezone stuff we use [Matt Johnson's SqlServerTimeZoneSupport/](https://github.com/mattjohnsonpint/SqlServerTimeZoneSupport/)
We convert datetimes on the fly using ConvertZone for our clients. Some Australian states support Daylight Savings, some don't.  Upgrading SQL Server is not possible.

I'm trying to solves an issue where `ConvertZone()` is returning null for dates in the last week. Probably related to daylight savings. I've tried fiddling with the spring forward and fall back bits to no success.

Listed below is a test case:

```
DECLARE @dates table
(
    [Start] datetime,
    [End] datetime
)

insert into @dates([Start], [End])
VALUES
('2021-04-05 06:51:06.000', '2021-04-05 06:51:06.000'),
('2021-04-05 18:47:00.000', '2021-04-05 18:47:00.000'),
('2021-04-05 19:45:24.000', '2021-04-05 20:12:00.000'),
('2021-04-05 05:29:00.000', '2021-04-05 05:29:06.000'),
('2021-04-05 11:23:32.000', '2021-04-05 11:23:32.000'),
('2021-04-05 17:23:56.000', '2021-04-05 17:23:56.000'),
('2021-04-05 06:34:56.000', '2021-04-05 06:39:30.000'),
('2021-04-05 06:51:35.000', '2021-04-05 06:54:30.000'),
('2021-04-05 08:05:48.000', '2021-04-05 08:07:30.000'),
('2021-04-05 08:34:09.000', '2021-04-05 08:34:30.000'),
('2021-04-05 10:42:13.000', '2021-04-05 10:46:00.000'),
('2021-04-11 14:24:58.000', '2021-04-11 14:30:30.000'),
('2021-04-11 17:11:26.000', '2021-04-11 17:19:39.000'),
('2021-04-11 06:55:17.000', '2021-04-11 06:55:30.000'),
('2021-04-11 18:25:19.000', '2021-04-11 18:25:37.000'),
('2021-04-11 18:27:21.000', '2021-04-11 18:27:30.000'),
('2021-04-11 18:28:23.000', '2021-04-11 18:28:30.000'),
('2021-04-11 18:28:48.000', '2021-04-11 18:30:43.000')

SELECT
    [Start],
    CONVERT(datetime, Tzdb.ConvertZone([start], 'Australia/NSW', 'Australia/Queensland', 1, 1)) as StartAdjusted,
    [End],
    CONVERT(datetime, Tzdb.ConvertZone([end], 'Australia/NSW', 'Australia/Queensland', 1, 1)) as EndAdjusted
FROM @dates
```

`Tzdb.ConvertZone()` is installed from the SQLServerTimeZoneSupport git linked above.  Its created as it's own TZDB schema.

All of these adjusted dates return NULL. Any advice?

Comment: [The author states](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65694155/1127428) "Alternatively, if for some reason you must do this entirely in SQL Server without converting to Windows time zones, then you will need to rely on projects such as my SqlServerTimeZoneSupport project. That one is a bit old and not very well maintained, so I recommend against that approach if you can help it."

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its a question intended for the support team of the component.

Comment: You could trying pinging the author by adding a comment to his answer above...

Comment: I was actually hoping for other users with timezone knowledge to comment.  I have created a ticket on git for the author.

Comment: @matt-johnson-pint are you there?

https://stackoverflow.com/users/634824/matt-johnson-pint

Comment: Yes, but I'm a bit tied up at the moment.  Will investigate when I have availability.

Comment: Ty Matt. Dirty fix at the moment is unadjusted date is displayed :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@matt-johnson-pint suggested I refresh my Timezone tables.  This involved downloading and using the SqlTzLoader from the Project page, running for each server (set the correct connection string).  I was confused, as it outputs no text if successful, but it fixed the issue.  My test case is now fine.